# Questions on Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory

Reading through Schoof's notes on Algebraic Number Theory I have encountered a few questions I can't answer:

(1) Given an algebraic number field F, why is the number of real and complex zeroes the same for any minimal polynomial of a primitive element?

(2) Why does the minimal polynomial of a primitive element have distinct roots?

Comment: For question (2), all elements of an algebraic extension are separable in characteristic 0.

Comment: Who is Schoof? A professor? Are his lecture notes in book form?

Comment: I suspect (1) is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra... http://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Fund_theorem_of_algebra.html

Comment: @Bernard that works, thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Brooks I am looking at his notes on algebraic number theory, which you can find just by googling "Schoof algebraic number theory"

Comment: Would that be http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~eal/moonen.pdf ?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: For question $(1)$, while calculating the number of real and complex embedding, we do not use primitive element. Therefore, the number of real and complex zeroes the same for any minimal polynomial of a primitive element.